# How to copy 2 arrays into 1 array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am making 2 ajax requests to get different data from different servers.

```
server 1 response
==================
[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]

server 2 response
==================
[{id:4},{id:5},{id:6}]
```

How can I combine these two arrays into one like

```
[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5},{id:6}]
```

I don't want to loop through each array and push it to new array, because I'll get 1000's of records.

Comment: [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: You can read [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

Comment: The problem is I'll get 2 responses in 2 different times

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can *concatenate two* different array,

#### jQuery

```
var server1 = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
var server2 = [{id:4},{id:5},{id:6}];
$.merge( $.merge( [], server1 ), server2 );
//console.log($.merge( $.merge( [], server1 ), server2 ));
```

***Result***

```
[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5},{id:6}]
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCLAq/)**</kbd>

---

#### Javascript

```
var server1 = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
var server2 = [{id:4},{id:5},{id:6}];
CombineArray = server1.concat(server2);
```

***Result***

```
CombineArray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5},{id:6}]
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DA439/)**</kbd>

Hope this both are help you!